# Regex: Change Jenkinsfile parameterDefinitions format

Tags: python, scripting, jenkins-pipeline

I have tons of Jenkins files with different format of `parameterDefinitions`

So I want to change the format of all the files below like this

```
parameterDefinitions: [
    [
        $class: 'hudson.model.BooleanParameterDefinition',
        name: 'FOO_BAR',
        defaultValue: true,
        description: "Foo bar, chunky bacon",
    ]
]
```

to

```
parameterDefinitions: [
    booleanParam(
        name: "FOO_BAR",
        defaultValue: true,
        description: "Foo bar, chunky bacon",
    )
]
```

Is there any way to do that by using regex/scripting or like python?

Comment: What's the file format called you are using. Those aren't JSONs. Often times those unique file formats also have libraries you can use.

Comment: @TinNguyen I am using Jenkinsfile and it's scripted-pipeline syntax and I search the on the Github haven't found any libraries.